# Is it possible to call multiple methods in "ng-submit"?

Tags: angularjs

I know this works for ng-click, but it doesn't seem to be working for ng-submit. This is what I'm trying to do

```
ng-submit="methodA(); methodB();"
```

Comment: Can you not just create a common method for these two methods, and just call that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes its possible check example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DkSGmNJjFkwac1CKauCj?p=preview)

```
angular.module('submitExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.list = [];
       $scope.text = 'hello';
       $scope.a = function(){
         alert(0);
       }
       $scope.submit = function() {
         if ($scope.text) {
           $scope.list.push(this.text);
           $scope.text = '';
         }
       };
     }]);
```

And the markup:

```
 <form ng-submit="submit(); a()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   Enter text and hit enter:
   <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
   <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
 </form>
```

Comment: are u know which method is fire first from submit() or a()..?

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can do it like :

```
ng-submit="methodA(); methodB();"
```

[see plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u9hqu1bASxxMgtEP1qAr?p=preview)